# cannot insert more than 16 columns using SQLServerBulkCopy

Tags: java, sql-server, bcp

I am using the Bulk Copy code from MSDN website, nothing changed actually. I have the table with correct columns in DB (SQLServer 2008 R2 Management Studio 10). But when I tried to run this code, on the addColumnMetadata line throw an exception:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Column 17 is invalid.
>   Please check your column mappings.    at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.validateColumnMappings(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:1747)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.writeToServer(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:1514)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.writeToServer(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:628)

I cannot find the bug. Can anyone please help me? Below is part of the code copied from MSDN. The for loop and file path are the only things I changed.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String connectionString = GetConnectionString();
    SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord fileRecord = null;
    try
    {            
        // Get data from the source file by loading it into a class that implements ISQLServerBulkRecord.
        // Here we are using the SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord implementation to import the example CSV file.
        fileRecord = new SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord("F:/test/test1.csv", true);    

        // Set the metadata for each column to be copied.
        for(int i = 0;i < 17;i++)
        {
            fileRecord.addColumnMetadata(i+1, null, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR, 10, 0);
        }

        // Open a destinationConnectio to the AdventureWorks database. 
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        try (Connection destinationConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try (Statement stmt = destinationConnection.createStatement())
            {
                // Perform an initial count on the destination table.
                long countStart = 0;
                try (ResultSet rsRowCount = stmt.executeQuery(
                        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.BulkCopyDemoDifferentColumns1;"))
                {
                    rsRowCount.next();
                    countStart = rsRowCount.getInt(1);
                    System.out.println("Starting row count = " + countStart);
                }

                // Set up the bulk copy object.  
                // Note that the column positions in the source 
                // data reader match the column positions in  
                // the destination table so there is no need to 
                // map columns. 
                try (SQLServerBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                           new SQLServerBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
                {
                    bulkCopy.setDestinationTableName("dbo.BulkCopyDemoDifferentColumns1");

                    try
                    {
                        // Write from the source to the destination.
                        bulkCopy.writeToServer(fileRecord);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                // Perform a final count on the destination  
                // table to see how many rows were added.
                try (ResultSet rsRowCount = stmt.executeQuery(
                        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.BulkCopyDemoDifferentColumns1;"))
                {
                    rsRowCount.next();
                    long countEnd = rsRowCount.getInt(1);
                    System.out.println("Ending row count = " + countEnd);
                    System.out.println((countEnd - countStart) + " rows were added.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fileRecord != null) try { fileRecord.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Everything works well with less than 17 columns. Complete code is at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt221490(v=sql.110).aspx)

Here is the table structure:
create table BulkCopyDemoDifferentColumns1
(
    name1 VARCHAR(10),
    name2 VARCHAR(10),
    name3 VARCHAR(10),
    name4 VARCHAR(10),
    name5 VARCHAR(10),
    name6 VARCHAR(10),
    name7 VARCHAR(10),
    name8 VARCHAR(10),
    name9 VARCHAR(10),
    name10 VARCHAR(10),
    name11 VARCHAR(10),
    name12 VARCHAR(10),
    name13 VARCHAR(10),
    name14 VARCHAR(10),
    name15 VARCHAR(10),
    name16 VARCHAR(10),
    name17 VARCHAR(10)
    )

Comment: Everything works well with less than 17 columns. Complete code is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt221490(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: What kind of data is in your 17th column? It looks like it might be larger than the amount you allow it to have.

Comment: All the 17 columns are VARCHAR(10) and the 17th value is "17". This error does not make any sense because it works fine for the first 16 columns and the 17th column is almost the copy of the first 16 columns.

Comment: Well you are looping from 1 to 17, and adding columns to the `fileRecord` object. It looks like some of your code is missing, but I am guessing you are later accessing something like `fileRecord.Columns[17]`. If that is the case, that will blow up, index 17 doesn't exist. It goes from `0` to `16`, which is 17 elements. Or if it is blowing up on the `.addColumnMetadata` call, again you should probably be using `for(int i =0; i<=16; i++)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have attached the full code and changed the loop starting from 0. The error happens at  bulkCopy.writeToServer(fileRecord); The csv file just contains two lines, the 1st line is the header, the second line is the data from "1" to "17", separated by comma.

Comment: Then I would look at `dbo.BulkCopyDemoDifferentColumns1` table. Can you provide the design specs for that table? Also, it is best not to modify the code you are questioning to incorporate suggestions. Only to include more when requested or to correct a typo related to your original question.

Comment: Also, you changed your `for` loop, but then in the `addColumnMetadata` call you use `i+1`, you should just be using `i`, c# arrays are 0 based. The first element is always 0 and the last element is `Count - 1`. So unless you do not want to access the first element you should change it to just `i` instead of `i+1`.

Comment: The reason I use i+1 is on MSDN the sample code starts from 1 not 0. If I starts from 0, it will throw an exception saying "Column number should be greater than zero."

Comment: Add the table structure to your question so you can format it, but it looks like it is 17 columns. I am still suspicious about that for loop and going from 1 to 17 instead of 0 to 16. What language  is the MSDN example in? Try to examine the properties and anything about the `fileRecord` object. Something is not matching up correctly with how it is set up and the table it is trying to write out to.

Comment: The MSDN sample code is using JAVA.

Comment: Are you positive the database/table you are working with is the correct one?If you select a particular row and write it out in your code, do you get the correct data? Is it possible you are accessing a different table than what you are expecting?

Comment: I am sure I am using the correct table. I tried to read the source code but it is not easy to read.

Comment: I mean, is it possible that you are connecting to the wrong database server or a copy of the table residing in a different schema? Or possibly a synonym pointing to a table that it shouldn't be..

Comment: Which version you are using? sqljdbc42.jar or sqljdbc41.jar ?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the csv file has 2 rows, the first being a header. 

The SQLServerBulkCopy object requires that the row terminates with `\r\n` and not just `\n`. Make sure this is the case with your CSV.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But after I make sure all the two lines are terminated with \r\n. Actually the point I cant understand is it is working fine for 16 columns but there is no way for the 17th column it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

using jdk 1.8 works.
If you use jre7 it doesn't work even if you change to the last driver mssql-jdbc 6.4.0.jre7 :(